# Raster stack values mostly NA but in ArcGIS Pro hardly any NA values in extent

Tags: raster, nearest-neighbor

I am predicting a machine learning model onto a set of continuous and categorical spatial explanatory variables in R. When I take a look at the raster stack (called Ras1) values using:

```
values(Ras1)
```

most of the columns have NA values. Since my layers are categorical when I resampled the rasters I used the nearest neighbor method. I can't figure out why all the NA values but it must be something in my code:

```
rastlist <- list.files(path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Rasters', pattern='.tif$', all.files=TRUE, full.names=T)

#import all tiff files into raster using lapply
allrasters <- lapply(rastlist, raster)

allrasters <- raster::stack(allrasters)

#read shape file of StudyArea
StudyArea <- terra::vect(x = "C:/Users/Desktop/Rasters/StudyArea.shp", 
layer = "StudyArea")

#match the extent of all rasters to an arbitrary raster in stack
extent(allrasters[[1]])

#need to change one raster crs to be the same as another
#allrasters[[2]] <- projectRaster(allrasters[[2]], 
 crs=crs(allrasters[[3]]), method='ngb')

##Creating a function to make a polygon of each raster's extent##
fxn<-function(ras){
  bb<-bbox(ras)
  bbpoly<-bb_poly(bb)
  st_crs(bbpoly)<-crs(ras)
  return(as_Spatial(bbpoly))
}

ext<-lapply(allrasters, FUN=fxn)

##Aggregating and dissolving all extents##
full.ext<-aggregate(do.call(bind, ext), dissolve=TRUE)

##Creating a blank raster with the full extent, the desired final projection, and the desired resolution##
blank<-raster(ext=extent(full.ext), nrow=allrasters[[3]]@nrows, ncol=allrasters[[3]]@ncols, crs=allrasters[[3]]@crs)

##Resampling all rasters to desired extent nearest neighbor is used##
rastostack <-lapply(allrasters, FUN = resample, blank, method='ngb')

##Stacking the rasters##
Ras <- raster::stack(rastostack)
Ras 

#rename layers in raster stack to match the names in the models
name <- c("Age", "Drainage", "HSG", "LU2005", "LU1990", "LU1975", "LU1960", 
"LU1945", "NO3_180", "NO3_400", "DO5", "DO2", "Precip")

#apply those names to the raster
Ras1 <- Ras[[name]]

#check layer name and order
Ras1@layers

#extracting values from rasters so I can apply model and bias correction
val <- values(Ras1)
val<- as.data.table(val)

#clean up table by rounding and replacing numbers that really mean NA)
val$Drainage <- round(val$Drainage, digits=0)
val$HSG <- round(val$HSG, digits=0)
val$LU1945 <- round(val$LU1945, digits=0)

# replace values of some pixel values which I know to be do NoData
val$LU1945[val$LU1945==128] <- ''
val$LU1945[val$LU1945==0] <- ''

#make categorical variables factors
val$Drainage <- as.factor(val$Drainage)
val$LU1945 <- as.factor(val$LU1945)

#call model
rfcaret_1000 <- readRDS("rfcaret_1000.Rds")

# predict model to values from raster
map<- predict(rfcaret_1000, val, type="raw")
```

But when I look at the table val it almost all the cell values are NA so something must be wrong in the process of making the stack or resampling? [This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330659/r-raster-returns-values-as-na) shows a similar problem but I have checked CRS and all layers seem to match.